# How can VBA application use the correct built in styles across English and French versions of Windows/Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I developed a Word 2003 report generation application that extracts data from a database.

Most of the organization uses English versions of Windows and Office. But, many users in our French office use their local versions. If I use any of Word's built-in Heading styles Heading (1-9), the French version expects Titre (1-9).

In my current solution, the user sets a Form option and VBA does the following:

```
Dim HeadingStyle as String
Dim HeadingLevel as Integer


If ChooseReportFrm.FrenchOpt.Value = True Then 
 HeadingStyle = "Titre "
Else
 HeadingStyle = "Heading "
End If
...

Call InsertText(HeadingStyle & CStr(HeadingLevel))
```

I would like to make this process automatic and completely transparent to the user. I have been searching in vain for a location-independent way to set the correct style, such as an enumerated constant. Does anybody have any ideas for a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [`WdBuiltinStyle` Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdbuiltinstyle(VS.80).aspx).

When assigning styles, you can do so by their [local name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.style.namelocal(office.11).aspx) (which is what you seem to do now), but you can also use one of the enumeration values, in your case setting the `Style` property to `WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading1` would do the trick.

```
Dim para As Paragraph
Set para = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1)

para.Style = WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading1
```

Comment: Good solution. I don't know how I never came accross this before. Thanks